# Cannot import snscrape module in python

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, twitter

I want to **scrape** some twitter data inside jupyter notebook. My python version is 3.9+ and when I run:

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
```

I got the following error:

```
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snscrape/modules/telegram.py in <module>
     23 
     24 @dataclasses.dataclass
---> 25 class TelegramPost(snscrape.base.Item):
     26         url: str
     27         date: datetime.datetime

/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snscrape/modules/telegram.py in TelegramPost()
     30         linkPreview: typing.Optional[LinkPreview] = None
     31 
---> 32         outlinksss = snscrape.base._DeprecatedProperty('outlinksss', lambda self: ' '.join(self.outlinks), 'outlinks')
     33 
     34         def __str__(self):

AttributeError: module 'snscrape.base' has no attribute '_DeprecatedProperty'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

ps: I already double check the system requirement and download the package use

```
pip3 install snscrape
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to python, but I think you need to install the developer package using the below code:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape.git
```

Comment: I have the same problem and the solution does not work